# Bootstrap - Radio buttons displaying as a box

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/f2bZf/)**...

In the fiddle, the radio buttons are displaying correctly.

```
<div class="element-radio" title="Do you want to float the text to the left, right, or not at all?"><h4 class="title" style="font-weight: bold;">Float (left, right or none)</h4>       
    <div class="column column3">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Left" />
                <span>Left</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    <div class="column column3">
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="Right" />
            <span>Right</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    <div class="column column3">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="None" />
                <span>None</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    </div>
```

However, in the website I'm working on, located [**here**](http://webfro.gs/south/EDMC_App_Portal/define_rif_assets.html), the radio buttons are displaying as tiny boxes, that are unclickable.

This is the Bootstrap CDN I'm using -

http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Additionally, this website works locally, but not once I get in on my server.

Ideas?

Comment: you are customizing radio boxes in sytle.css `.formoid-metro-cyan input[type=checkbox], .formoid-metro-cyan input[type=radio]`

Comment: Got it. You're both right, and I've fixed it. Who ever puts the answer up first, gets it.

Comment: Why was it downvoted? I displayed work, fiddle, etc.

Comment: Fix this in your HTML: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invalid reference as you are trying to load this file

```
file:///C:/Users/jnewnam/Documents/EDMC%20App%20Portal%20Redo/Formoid/html/logi‌​n_files/formoid1/formoid.ttf`
```

Comment: That was it. It's fixed. Thanks for that. I don't even know how that happened. Wasn't like that yesterday. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the opacity: 0.01; setting inside the following class in styles.css, the radio buttons will be rendered by the browser:

```
.formoid-metro-cyan input[type="checkbox"], .formoid-metro-cyan input[type="radio"] {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    opacity: 0.01; /*delete this*/
    margin: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```